# Operator precedence of "unary minus" (-) and exponentiation (^) outside vs. inside function

Tags: r, math, operator-precedence

Why does order of operation [PEMDAS] within functions work right in R?

These work fine:

```
-27^(1/3) == -3 # TRUE
-27^0.3333333333333333 == -3 # TRUE
```

But when used inside a function the result is `NaN`

```
foo <- function(x, y){return(x^(1/y))}
foo(x = -27, y = 3) # NaN

bar <- function(x, y){
    a = 1 / y
    b = x^a
    return(b)
}

bar(x = -27, y = 3) # NaN
```

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of the surprisingly low precedence of the "unary minus" (`-`) operator, combined with R's convention for raising negative numbers to fractional powers. `-27^(1/3)` is read as "calculate 27^(1/3) (==3), then invert the sign". If we instead compute `(-27)^(1/3)`, we get `NaN`, because a negative number can't reliably be raised to a fractional power. Whether the evaluation is inside or outside of a function is a red herring; the issue is whether (-27) is evaluated as an expression first (which it is if you assign it to a function argument or a variable, or put it in parentheses).

The precedence of unary minus is discussed on [this mailing list thread from 2009](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-July/397975.html) and [R FAQ 7.33](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-powers-of-negative-numbers-wrong_003f), and more generally in this [math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1299236/265374). There's a (rather technical) explanation of why a negative value to a fractional power is `NaN` in `?"^"`:

> Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example
> why `(-8)^(1/3)` is `NaN`.  For double inputs, R makes use of IEC
> 60559 arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system
> function `pow` for the `^` operator.  The relevant standards
> define the result in many corner cases.  In particular, the result
> in the example above is mandated by the C99 standard.  On many
> Unix-alike systems the command `man pow` gives details of the
> values in a large number of corner cases.